# Windows 7 CD Command only echoes directory

Tags: windows, shell

The path for every new instance of the shell starts in my user directory (C:\Users\user).

Within this directory or rather drive (in this case C:) I can't use the cd command as I'm used to - it only echoes the specified directory.

As soon as I change the directory to a parent-directory I can execute "cd D:" and it changes to the drive.

But this behavious doesn't appear consistently in all instances of the shell.

Sometimes I have to go to C: to change it.

I'm quite sure I'm not using the command in the wrong way, since it's what I'm used to do to start grails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To switch to another drive, just use that drive letter. The command `D:` switches to the D-drive. To change to another directory, say, the root of D:, you'll need two commands:

```
D:
cd D:\
(or)
D:
cd \
```

The Windows shell has an active directory for each drive/volume. If you specify the drive letter when you change the directory, you change the active directory for that volume, but you will not actually make that volume active too.

Comment: AAAh im so dumb. thanks for the clarification. Read the help entry of the command and with your comment I finally found my mistake.

Answer (score 3):

`cd` with just a drive only shows the current directory on that drive. Either pass the drive itself as a command to switch to its current directory (`d:`), or use `cd /d` to switch both drive and directory.

Comment: Further testing led me to a more specific problem. I edited the question.
In addition I'm trying to change the directory like D:\somefolder and just the drive.